# Display and capitalize the file name only without path

Tags: php

I am trying to display the capitalized filename only.
I have gotten this far which works perfectly in the root directory of the domain:

```
$path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; 
$path = str_replace('_', ' ', ($path));
$path = str_replace('/', '', ($path)); 
$path = ucwords($path);

echo basename ($path,".php");
```

However if I'm down a directory or two it returns the path also.

Example:
`/public_html/mydomain-com/one_two_three_four_five.php`

Result:
One Two Three Four Five // PERFECT what I want

Example:
`/public_html/mydomain-com/test/one_two_three_four_five.php`

Result:
Testone Two Three Four Five // NOT perfect

Example:
`/public_html/mydomain-com/test/pathtest/one_two_three_four_five.php`

Result:
Testpathtestone Two Three Four Five // NOT perfect

I cannot figure out how to get rid of the path and have searched everywhere for an answer but cannot find anything even close.

Also, is there something that will work for either/or both scenarios? (I hope)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$pos = strrpos($path, '/');
$path = substr($path, $pos);
$path = str_replace('_', ' ', $path);
$path = ucwords($path);
```

What this will do is find the last occurrence of `/`, and then return the substring after that. The rest of the script stays the same.

Comment: Ok now when I have for example dashes instead of underscores as separators it gives a 500 internal error.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Just replace the underscores with dashes in `str_replace`

Comment: Hi Ashwin! (and thanks) 

I did replace the underscore with a dash and it gives the error.

On another note can I have both in the same code?

Comment: If you have multiple patterns, then you should start looking into Regular Expressions.

Comment: OK here's the code that produces the 500 error:
$pos = strrpos($path, '/');
$path = substr($path, $pos);
 $path = str_replace('-', ' ', ($path));
 $path = str_replace('/', '', ($path));
 $path = ucwords($path);

Comment: It works fine with underscores but I change it to dashes and it gives the 500 error.

Comment: I was going to standardize all the files to the dash separator but ran into this snafu. Can't figure it out but the code works fine with underscore and I make the simple change from underscore to dash and get the 500 error. (which shows no system error)

Comment: I just posted a working example in my previous comment. You should really see how it works.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Ashwin! I figured it out - stray character in the code somehow that was throwing the error. Works fine now. Thanks again and sorry for being such a bonehead LOL!

Answer (score 0):

Try using explode() function to split the path into each foldername and filename, then capitalize the last element of the array and print out the array.

E.g:

```
$fields = explode('/', $path);

$fields[count($fields)-1] = ucwords($fields[count($fields)-1]);
$new_path = "";
foreach($fields as $field) {
    $new_path .= $field . ' ';
}

$new_path = str_replace('_', ' ', $new_path);
```